# Html injection problems on node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, html-injections

Hi i'm trying to inject html code from a String to a view and i'm getting some a error trying to, im stuck:

**This is the Code on Node.js route:**

```
router.get('/profile/:page', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    // Get current page from url (request parameter)
    let page_id = parseInt(req.params.page);
    let currentPage = 0;
    if (page_id > 0) currentPage = page_id;

    //Change pageUri to your page url without the 'page' query string 
    pageUri = '/profile/';


    /*Get total items*/
    await pool.query('SELECT COUNT(id) as totalCount FROM user where user_type="Client"', async (err, result,) => {

        // Display 10 items per page
        const perPage = 10,
            totalCount = result[0].totalCount;
        console.log("Estos son los datos",totalCount, currentPage, pageUri, perPage);
        // Instantiate Pagination class
        const Paginate = new Pagination(totalCount, currentPage, pageUri, perPage);


        /*Query items*/
        const data = {
            users: await pool.query('SELECT * FROM user where user_type="Client" LIMIT ' + 10 + ' OFFSET ' + Paginate.offset),
            pages: Paginate.links()// Paginate.lins()->return a variable with all html
        }

        res.render('profile', { data });
        
    });
});
```

**This is Links() function**

```
class Pagination{
    
    constructor(totalCount,currentPage,pageUri,perPage=2){
        this.perPage = perPage;
        this.totalCount =parseInt(totalCount);
        this.currentPage = parseInt(currentPage);
        this.previousPage = this.currentPage - 1;
        this.nextPage = this.currentPage + 1;
        this.pageCount = Math.ceil(this.totalCount / this.perPage);
        this.pageUri = pageUri;
        this.offset  = this.currentPage > 1 ? this.previousPage * this.perPage : 0;
        this.sidePages = 4;
        this.pages = false;
    }
    
    
    
    links(){
        this.pages='<ul class="pagination pagination-md">';
    
        if(this.previousPage > 0)
            this.pages+='<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'+this.pageUri + this.previousPage+'">Previous</a></li>';
    
    
            /*Add back links*/
            if(this.currentPage > 1){
                for (var x = this.currentPage - this.sidePages; x < this.currentPage; x++) {
                    if(x > 0)
                        this.pages+='<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'+this.pageUri+x+'">'+x+'</a></li>';
                }
            }
    
            /*Show current page*/
            this.pages+='<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="'+this.pageUri+this.currentPage+'">'+this.currentPage+'</a></li>';
    
            /*Add more links*/
            for(x = this.nextPage; x <= this.pageCount; x++){
    
                this.pages+='<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'+this.pageUri+x+'">'+x+' </a></li>';
    
                if(x >= this.currentPage + this.sidePages)
                    break;
            }
    
    
            /*Display next buttton navigation*/
            if(this.currentPage + 1 <= this.pageCount)
                this.pages+='<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'+this.pageUri+this.nextPage+'">Next</a></li>';
    
            this.pages+='</ul>';
    
        return this.pages;
    }

    

    }
    module.exports = Pagination;
```

**In the HTML:**

```
<div id="pages">
                               
{{ data.pages }}

</div>
```

Finally I am getting an error in my browser which does not allow the html that I send from the path to read correctly.
PLZZ HELP ME. IM STUCK

This is pool:
`const pool = require('../database');`

And this is database.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const { promisify } = require ('util');

const { database } = require('./keys');
const pool= mysql.createPool(database);

pool.getConnection((err, connection)=>{
    if(err){
        if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'){
            console.error('DATABASE CONNECTION WAS CLOSED');
        }
        if(err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR'){
            console.error('DATABASE HAS TO MANY CONNECTIONS');
        }
        if(err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED'){
            console.error('DATABASE CONNECTION WAS REFUSED');
        }
    }
    if (connection) connection.release();
    console.log('DB is CONNECTED');
    return;
});

//Promisify Pool Querys
pool.query = promisify(pool.query);

module.exports = pool;
```

Also the browser detect only text, not code.

**View Source in the browser**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK0Vz.png)

Which exact database library are you using?
require('mysql')

And, what exactly is the error in your browser?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sco2E.png)

Comment: Please do View Source in the browser and post the exact HTML for the whole page that is generated so we can see that.

Comment: Which exact database library are you using?  Does it support promises for `pool.query()`?

Comment: And, what exactly is the error in your browser?

Comment: sorry about not responding at time,  i have work, i have solved

Comment: `<script>
    var a = document.getElementById("pages").value;
    document.getElementById("s").innerHTML= a;
</script>`

Comment: Well, you can delete your question then.  It shouldn't just be left here in this state.

Comment: ` <textarea id="pages" hidden>
                                {{ data.pages }}
                            </textarea>
                            <div id="s">

                            </div> ` Use a txtarea in conjunction with a script, so that it recognizes the html code

Comment: FYI, that's not a very efficient way to inject HTML.  You're already using a server-side template engine.  You should just inject the HTML directly at the server, not inject text and then using client-side Javascript to insert the HTML into the page.

Comment: Then how do i inject the html code from server side?

Comment: Well, you can start by answering the questions I asked you a couple hours ago.  There are four separate questions asked.

Comment: Done i posted, if you need more info, i`ll post it

Comment: That image is not the result of `View/Source`.  That's a DOM screenshot.  I want to see the actual HTML that the page generates.  In Chrome, right click in the page and select "View Page Source".

Comment: And, which template engine are you using?  Please show the Express code where you initialize the template engine.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Post formatted text instead.

Comment: FYI, it looks like your template engine is escaping the HTML you're trying to put in it which makes it display as text, not as HTML.  I don't know which template engine you're using so I can't suggest a proper fix.  But, the fix will be easy once I know what template engine you're using and the View Page Source would also confirm that this is what is happening which is why I asked for it.

Comment: Im using handlebar, I'm thinking that I should do a helper on handelbars

Comment: @AlejandroDavidLópezVega - See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template engine by default escapes any text that you insert into the page so it will be rendered as text and not accidentally interpreted as HTML.  This is why the HTML you inject is displaying as plain text.

If you want to inject actual HTML, then you have to tell the template engine that you don't want it to escape this particular insertion.  When you tell us what template engine you're using, we can help you with how you do that.

To stop Handlebars from escaping your HTML, just use triple braces like this:

```
<div id="pages">
                               
{{{ data.pages }}}

</div>
```

Here's the relevant [doc page](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping) that describes it.

---

Also, `await` does not work with `pool.query()` in either of the places you're using it because the mysql module does not support promises and thus `await` on something other than a promise does nothing useful.  You can use the mysql2 module as in `require('mysql2/promise')` to get built-in promise support with mysql2.  Then, don't pass a callback and just use the returned promise.